# Show text in primary and accent color

Tags: angular, angular-material

I guess it's a dumb question. I want some text in a regular paragraph in accent color. E.g.

```
<p class="highlight">This text should be in material's current accent color</p>
```

I can set the text color in my stylesheet to any color, e.g.:

```
.hightlight {
    color: red;
}
```

But I do not know how to set it to the 'accent' color.

Comment: So I think you are asking "how do I access material theme colors in my (s)css files?", you can find more information about this here: https://material.angular.io/guide/theming-your-components

Comment: Thank you. Google tended to point me to that article too, but I ignored it, because I thought it would be about creating my own theme. Now I read it, and it became clear, that my "simply use a theme color in my component" is "theming my component".

One more question: The article is based on a sccs variable `$theme`. Once I have that, it's fine. I understand that and how I can create my own theme, very easy indeed. But if I want to stick with the default theme, how would I get access to it?